# move through array items to generate a ranking table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that I'm trying to show stock items for sale inside it, the 100 table items are pulled via Ajax on runtime, I want to show only 20 items every 3 seconds, looping through the items forward like this:

**Second 1**

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4 ..

**After 3 seconds**

- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5 ..

**After 3 seconds**

- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 6 ..

**After 3 seconds**

- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 6
- Item 7 ..

What I did so far is:

```
$('.market-items-count').html(marketItems.length);

            setTimeout(function(){ 

                $('.market-data tr').hide();
                setInterval(function(){         
                    $('.market-data tr').each(function(index, element){             
                        if(index == 0)
                        {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }

                        if(index < 20 )
                        {
                            $(this).show('slow');
                        }
                    }); 
                }, 3000); 
            }, 3000);
```

I am looking for a better way please with AngularJS.

```
     app.controller("marketController", ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $filter, $rootScope) {

            $scope.marketItems = [];
            $http.get(window.APPURL + '/api/market').then(function(response) {
                $scope.marketItems = response.data;
            });
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to this `limitTo` in `ng-repeat`, and then from js set `$interval`, which after every 3 seconds will show next items:
HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="d in data | limitTo:totalDisplayed">
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{d.item}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $interval) {


  $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'templates.json',
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
                console.log($scope.data)

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
 $scope.totalDisplayed = 3;

 $interval(function(){
            $scope.totalDisplayed += 1;
        }, 3000);
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/20ZCDdO7WGBgkHu77rrI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but this is not I requested. I managed to solve the issue and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to make this simple solution (Ex: show 3 items at a time):

```
var marketItems = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7","item 8", "item 9", "item 10","item 11", "item 12"];

var data = [];      
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 
    data = marketItems.slice(i, 3 + i + 1);
    i++;
    console.log(data);
}, 3000);
```

Thanks.